# Force mount location for USB cameras

Tags: 16.04, usb, mount, webcam, camera

I'm using two USB cameras for a project, one regular cam and one stereo cam. 
The regular camera has two mount locations with different output formats in each, /dev/video0 and /dev/video1. The stereo camera is mounted on /dev/video2.

When I unplug, restart or do some changes to the setup, the mount locations often switch. Is it possible to have the cameras always mount to the same locations somehow?